# How can I prepare a SVG for canvg() in IE 8?

Tags: jquery, dom, svg, html5-canvas, canvg

I'm trying to use canvg to rasterize a SVG image embedded in my document. The following code produces correct output in Firefox 17:

```
//svg is a jQuery object that we selected earlier
//canvas is a canvas created earlier
//use a temporary DOM object to serialize the SVG DOM object into text;
var tmpContainer = $(document.createElement('div'));
tmpContainer.append(svg.clone());
var svgText = tmpContainer.get(0).innerHTML;
canvg(canvas.get(0), svgText);
```

However, in IE 8 (the other browser my organization supports), `svgText` never picks up a value. I've tried other options, like the `html()` method from jQuery with little success--after all, it's not really html.

My question is this: **how can I get the SVG as a string of text in IE8? Are there other ways I can pass this to `canvg()` that I'm just not thinking of?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I've got bad news. Ready? Here goes:

*There is no such thing as SVG in Internet Explorer 8*.

Once I actually *looked* at the page source using the debugger, I found out that Google Charts (and any other Javascript charting library, for that matter) uses VML instead of SVG for charts. This means I can't use `canvg()` or anything else as things stand.

My options are as follows:

- **Use node.js to create SVG charts server-side.** [David Padbury](http://blog.davidpadbury.com/2010/10/03/using-nodejs-to-render-js-charts-on-server/) goes over how to do this with Highcharts. There's a lot of expansion that'd be needed, but the basic idea remains the same. This is the most likely to work, but I know nothing about node.js. Also, I'd need to design the interface between my server and client intelligently so that I don't end up with two scripts to maintain.
- **Try pursuing a VML conversion utility**. This is not looking very promising. But, this is what my JavaScript has to work with, so if I wanted to keep it client-side, this is the most direct approach.
- **Try adding SVG support to IE 8**. There are javascript libraries like [svgweb](https://code.google.com/p/svgweb/), and plugins like [Adobe's](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/svg/adobe-svg-viewer-download-area.html), which try to add SVG support to the browser. But, there are some issues.

  - Since the web has mostly forgotten about IE 8, these options have stagnated in support. The last commit to svgweb was in Feb 2011, and Adobe stopped supporting their plugin at the end of 2008.
  - I also don't know if Google Charts is doing feature-testing for SVG support, so it may simply still use VML to create the charts.